# AWS Cognito remember device

Tags: amazon-cognito

1 Why would AWS use/depend on local storage for tracking/remembering device? In our use case, we need to clear local storage every time the user logs out. How can we possibly take care of remembered device then?

2 If I want a device to be enabled only for 30 days or 15 days, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito doesn't depend on local storage for tracking/remember device. Take a look on Cognito:Userpool DeviceConfiguration setting in Cloudformation. Cognito can keep track of all the devices. Here's sample code

```
DeviceConfiguration:
        ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: False
        DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: False
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do you get this information from?